# Distributed TensorFlow: about the using of tf.train.Supervisor.start_queue_runners

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

I'm looking into the code for [distributed inception model in TF](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception), in which I have below questions about the use of `tf.train.Supervisor.start_queue_runners` in [inception_distributed_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py):

1. Why do we need to explicitly call `sv.start_queue_runners()` in line
   `264` and line `269` in [inception_distributed_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py)? In [API
   doc. of start_queue_runners](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/distributed_execution#Supervisor.start_queue_runners), I see there is no need for such
   calls due to:

   > Note that the queue runners collected in the graph key QUEUE_RUNNERS
   >   are already started automatically when you create a session with the
   >   supervisor, so unless you have non-collected queue runners to start
   >   you do not need to call this explicitly.
2. I noticed the values of `queue_runners` in calling
   `sv.start_queue_runners` are different in line `264` and line
   `269` in [inception_distributed_train.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py). But aren't
   `chief_queue_runners` also in the collection of
   `tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS` (all `QUEUE_RUNNERS` are obtained in line `263`)? If
   so, then there is no need for line `269` since the `chief_queue_runners` has already
   been started in line `264`.
3. Besides, could you please explain to me or show me some references about what queues are created in `tf.train.Supervisor`?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but some general notes how to find an answer :)

First of all, using github's blame, inception_distributed was checked in on April 13, while that comment in `start_queue_runners` was added on Apr 15th, so it's possible that functionality was changed but didn't get updated in all the places that use it.

You could comment-out that line and see if things still work. And if not, you could add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in the place where queue runner gets created (ie [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dd01113c2b9efb16c3c3ea0a4aaa340a0494696f/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py#L47)) and see who is creating those extra unattended queue runners.

Also, Supervisor development seems to have slowed down and things are getting moved over to FooSession (from comment [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6604#issuecomment-270950324)). Those provide a more robust training architecture (your workers won't crash because of temporary network error), but there are not many examples on how to use them yet.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Yaroslav! I asked the questions for getting some quick answers and I will check those issues. Besides, your information about moving to FooSession is valuable.